# database "telegraf" creation failed: 401 Unauthorized

Tags: database, grafana, monitoring, influxdb, telegraf

I tried to create a project as part of my studies using AWS EC2, docker, Grafana, InfluxDB and Telegraf.

I created EC2, installed Docker, created Grafana and InfluxaDB containers, and installed Telegraf on the machine. **Everything I did is on my github.**

https://github.com/jeti20/Docker-InfluxDB-Grafana.Telegraf

Unfortunately, when I turn on Telegraf, I encounter a problem. After entering "sudo journalctl -f -u telegraf.service" I get the information:

**telegraf[2304]: 2024-03-24T19:52:55Z W! [outputs.influxdb] When writing to [http://hereIsMyEC2IP:8086]: database "telegraf" creation failed: 401 Unauthorized

[outputs.influxdb] E! [outputs.influxdb] Failed to write metric (will be dropped: 401 Unauthorized):**

I'm doing this for the first time so I'm not sure if it is problem with this token or maybe with permissions, not sure, I spend 2 days on this and dont know what to do next.

I will be grateful for feedback about the architecture if it is bad tell me why, I will be grateful for the feedback because I want to learn.